# Failure to save data to HealthKit (Cocoa error 4097)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm currently having difficulty saving data to health kit and I'm unsure what the problem is.  I have health kit enabled and have granted read and write permissions on my testing device when the app runs (everything looks OK and I'm able to query the health kit database without error).  I'm using Swift.

The code I'm using to save is:

```
hksaver.healthStore!.saveObjects(samples, withCompletion: {
        (success: Bool , error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if success { ... } else {
            println("Failed to save. Error: \(error)")
            }
```

samples is an array of HKQuantity Samples.  It is created by appending 'dataSample' as defined below:

```
let dataPoint = HKQuantity(unit: units, doubleValue: measurement.dataPoint)

let dataSample = HKQuantitySample(type: quantityType,
            quantity: dataPoint, startDate: measurement.startDate,
            endDate: measurement.endDate, metadata: metadata)
```

There are no errors when constructing this, so I believe that all the values are appropriate.

When I run, I'm getting the following error:

> Failed to save. Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "The
>   operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4097.)" (connection to
>   service named com.apple.healthd.server) UserInfo=0x17047a0c0
>   {NSDebugDescription=connection to service named
>   com.apple.healthd.server}

I'm trying to write ~100,000 values to HealthKit though I haven't been able to find any limits (the same error occurred when I was trying to write ~50,000 values).  I've tried to write this in chunks, but after around 5 calls to health kit it starts failing (I'm assuming there is a limit to prevent continuous calls although I haven't seen anything in any documentation I've looked at).

I've tried searching under the error code, under the entire error, and under everything I could think of to explain the problem.  The only results I've returned deal with HomeKit and tend to be that it is not activated.  However under the capabilities tab I have HealthKit turned on and everything is check marked so I don't think that is the problem.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: I am getting a similar error, would love to have an answer too! http://stackoverflow.com/q/29068172/401543?sem=2

Comment: So far I'm still stumped - though I've been working on another project and not actively trying to solve this one at the moment.  Thanks for the link to you're question, I see a few answers there; maybe I can glean some insight.

Comment: Dunno if this helps, found this SO post..its for a different library but same error code    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33935175/error-loading-media-sources-in-mlmedialibrary   hope it helps

Comment: Could it be that the device is asleep/locked when you are trying to save the data? That would cause an error because Healthkit data is encrypted and unaccessible to apps when the device is locked.

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/8199

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibEhsan Thanks, though that isn't the problem.  This works unless I'm writing a large amount of data (so if I do 50 records for example, it works fine).

Comment: @owlswipe I don't think this is the case since I'm not allowing the phone to lock, and it only takes a minute or two in order to get to this point.