# What is the cause of this HealthKit error: "An error occurred while adding a sample to the workout"?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, healthkit

I understand why, but the ambiguity of the errors that HealthKit puts out is a total black box. Why am I getting the error:

> An error occurred while adding a sample to the workout: The operation couldn’t be completed.

I've been scouring the web for examples, but most of them are in swift. :(

Here's my code:

```
- (NSSet *)dataTypesToRead {
    HKQuantityType *heartRate = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate];

    return [NSSet setWithObjects:heartRate, nil];
}

- (NSSet *)dataTypesToWrite {
    HKWorkoutType* workout = [HKWorkoutType workoutType];
    HKQuantityType *energyBurnedType = [HKQuantityType  quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned];

    return [NSSet setWithObjects:workout, energyBurnedType, nil];
}

- (void)saveWorkout {

    HKHealthStore* healthStore = [[HKHealthStore alloc] init];

    NSDate* timeOfWorkout = [NSDate date];

    HKWorkoutType* type = [HKWorkoutType workoutType];

    [healthStore requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:[self dataTypesToWrite]
                                        readTypes:[self dataTypesToRead]
                                       completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

       if(success == YES)
       {
           // This sample uses hard-coded values and performs all the operations inline
           // for simplicity's sake. A real-world app would calculate these values
           // from sensor data and break the operation up using helper methods.

           HKQuantity *energyBurned =
           [HKQuantity quantityWithUnit:[HKUnit kilocalorieUnit]
                            doubleValue:333.0];

           HKQuantity *distance =
           [HKQuantity quantityWithUnit:[HKUnit mileUnit]
                            doubleValue:0.0];

           // Provide summary information when creating the workout.
           HKWorkout *workout = [HKWorkout workoutWithActivityType:HKWorkoutActivityTypeTraditionalStrengthTraining
                                                         startDate:timeOfWorkout
                                                           endDate:timeOfWorkout
                                                          duration:0
                                                 totalEnergyBurned:energyBurned
                                                     totalDistance:distance
                                                          metadata:nil];

           // Save the workout before adding detailed samples.
           [healthStore saveObject:workout withCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
               if (!success) {
                   // Perform proper error handling here...
                   NSLog(@"*** An error occurred while saving the "
                         @"workout: %@ ***", error.localizedDescription);

                   abort();
               }

           }];

           // Add optional, detailed information for each time interval
           NSMutableArray *samples = [NSMutableArray array];

           HKQuantityType *energyBurnedType =
           [HKObjectType quantityTypeForIdentifier:
            HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned];


           [samples addObject:energyBurnedType];

           // Add all the samples to the workout.
           [healthStore
            addSamples:samples
            toWorkout:workout
            completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                if (!success) {
                    // Perform proper error handling here...
                    NSLog(@"*** An error occurred while adding a "
                          @"sample to the workout: %@ ***",
                          error.localizedDescription);

                    abort();
                }
            }];
       }
       else
       {
           // Determine if it was an error or if the
           // user just canceld the authorization request
       }

   }];
}
```

Comment: Are there any messages in Console or crash logs on the device?  When you get a "the operation couldn’t be completed" error from a Cocoa API, it often indicates that some sort of failure occurred while communicating with the system daemon responsible for performing the operation.  For instance, in this case healthd could have crashed.

Comment: The only console message I get is:  "*** An error occurred while adding a sample to the workout: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4097.) ***"

Comment: That most likely means that healthd crashed in response to your request.  You should find the healthd crash log and then file a bug with Apple: http://bugreporter.apple.com.

Comment: @tshortli, check my answer in details that the crash is happened due to samples mutable array.  Which contains set of HKQuantityType objects, but it should be either HKQuantitySample or HKCategorySample.

Answer (score 1):

Here I find 2 issues,

1. Your trying to add samples to a workout before saving the workout in HealthKit.
2. *Samples* array should contain objects of type HKQuantitySample or HKCategorySample.

This is working fine...

```
- (NSSet *)dataTypesToRead {
    HKQuantityType *heartRate = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate];

    return [NSSet setWithObjects:heartRate, nil];
}

- (NSSet *)dataTypesToWrite {
    HKWorkoutType* workout = [HKWorkoutType workoutType];
    HKQuantityType *energyBurnedType = [HKQuantityType  quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned];

    return [NSSet setWithObjects:workout, energyBurnedType, nil];
}

- (void)saveWorkout {

    HKHealthStore* healthStore = [[HKHealthStore alloc] init];

    NSDate* timeOfWorkout = [NSDate date];

    [healthStore requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:[self dataTypesToWrite]
                                        readTypes:[self dataTypesToRead]
                                       completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

                                           if(success == YES)
                                           {
                                               // This sample uses hard-coded values and performs all the operations inline
                                               // for simplicity's sake. A real-world app would calculate these values
                                               // from sensor data and break the operation up using helper methods.

                                               HKQuantity *energyBurned =
                                               [HKQuantity quantityWithUnit:[HKUnit kilocalorieUnit]
                                                                doubleValue:333.0];

                                               HKQuantity *distance =
                                               [HKQuantity quantityWithUnit:[HKUnit mileUnit]
                                                                doubleValue:0.0];

                                               // Provide summary information when creating the workout.
                                               HKWorkout *workout = [HKWorkout workoutWithActivityType:HKWorkoutActivityTypeTraditionalStrengthTraining
                                                                                             startDate:timeOfWorkout
                                                                                               endDate:timeOfWorkout
                                                                                              duration:0
                                                                                     totalEnergyBurned:energyBurned
                                                                                         totalDistance:distance
                                                                                              metadata:nil];

                                               // Save the workout before adding detailed samples.
                                               [healthStore saveObject:workout withCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                                                   if (!success) {
                                                       // Perform proper error handling here...
                                                       NSLog(@"*** An error occurred while saving the "
                                                             @"workout: %@ ***", error.localizedDescription);

//                                                       abort();
                                                   }
                                                   else
                                                   {
                                                       // Add optional, detailed information for each time interval
                                                       NSMutableArray *samples = [NSMutableArray array];

                                                       HKQuantityType *energyBurnedType =
                                                       [HKObjectType quantityTypeForIdentifier:
                                                        HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned];

                                                       HKQuantity *energyBurnedQuantity = [HKQuantity quantityWithUnit:[HKUnit kilocalorieUnit] doubleValue:334];

                                                       HKQuantitySample *energyBurnedSample = [HKQuantitySample quantitySampleWithType:energyBurnedType quantity:energyBurnedQuantity startDate:[NSDate date] endDate:[NSDate date]];

                                                       [samples addObject:energyBurnedSample];

                                                       // Add all the samples to the workout.
                                                       [healthStore
                                                        addSamples:samples
                                                        toWorkout:workout
                                                        completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                                                            if (!success) {
                                                                // Perform proper error handling here...
                                                                NSLog(@"*** An error occurred while adding a "
                                                                      @"sample to the workout: %@ ***",
                                                                      error.localizedDescription);

                                                                //                                                        abort();
                                                            }
                                                        }];

                                                   }

                                               }];

                                           }
                                           else
                                           {
                                               // Determine if it was an error or if the
                                               // user just canceld the authorization request
                                           }

                                       }];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it I do see "334" kcal in HealthKit from a sample, which is what I need. One question, when HKWorkout object is created with workoutWithActivityType, the variable "energyBurned" is included as a parameter, which appears to not be used. Can I pass nil to this parameter since the HKSample is actually providing the kcal? If not how do I handle this extraneous code?

Comment: @MattMiller,  as per Apple's HealthKit design philosophy HKSample was a base class for HKQuantitySample and HKCategorySample classes.  The purpose of HKSample is to store the type of the sample to be stored in our case it is "HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned".  But, HKSample can't store the measurement(quantity/Category) of the data.  It is the responsibility of HKSample's sub-classes to store such data.  Even it is not possible to instantiate HKSample through "init" method.