# Error loading media sources in MLMediaLibrary

Tags: swift, macos

I'm getting an error while loading the `mediaSources` property in Mac OS X.
I'm trying to get the Apple Photos source using the `MLMediaLibrary` class.
My app is sandboxed, and has the read only permission for the pictures folder.
I'm getting the error:

> MLMediaLibrary error obtaining remote object proxy: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.MediaLibraryService" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.MediaLibraryService}

From what I gather, error 4097 is connection interrupted.
I'm not very familiar with Swift, but I did run the exact same test using objective C and got the same result.
My guess is that I'm missing an entitlement of some sort.

Here's my (very simplified) code:

```
import Foundation
import MediaLibrary

public class MediaLibrary : NSObject{
    var library : MLMediaLibrary!

    private func loadSources(){
        if let mediaSources = library.mediaSources {

            for (ident, source) in mediaSources{
                print("Identifier: \(ident)");
            }
        }

    }

    public override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        loadSources()
    }

    public override init(){
        super.init()
        let options : [String : AnyObject] = [MLMediaLoadSourceTypesKey : MLMediaSourceType.Image.rawValue, MLMediaLoadIncludeSourcesKey : MLMediaSourcePhotosIdentifier]
        library = MLMediaLibrary(options: options)
        library.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "mediaSource", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
        library.mediaSources; // trigger load, status will be reported back in observeValueForKeyPath
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW - also tried without sandboxing, same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out there were two things amiss:
1. The `MLMediaLoadIncludeSourcesKey` should point to an array of strings, not a single string
2. The observation key path was wrong, should be `"mediaSources"`, was missing an `s`

Comment: I am getting very similar error but on AVPlayer trying to load a video from URL site: See SO - "AVPlayer won't let me access URL"                                                       
startConfigurationWithCompletionHandler: Failed to get remote object proxy: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.rtcreportingd" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.rtcreportingd}
2017-11-10 19:48:50.095255-0800 AVPlayer[3784:207465] initWithSessionInfo: XPC connection interrupted  - Any ideas what this is?

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference: under Mojave, the app needs to be codesigned to have MLMediaLibrary working. Regular codesign or sandboxing worked.